# Excel Lookup Formula not working properly

Tags: excel

I am working off of sheet1 that is set out like:

Colum One: (First Name) Colum Two: (Last Name) Colum Three: (Account ID) Etc.

I have another sheet2 within this file with just:

Colum One: (First Name) Colum Two: (Last Name) Colum Three: (Account ID)

I would like to be able to prepopulate the (First Name) and (Last Name) when I enter the (Account ID).

I have tried doing this in many different ways, and I have searched the web and tried coping other example but still cannot get it to work.

I had the formula as "=vlookup(c3,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$10,1,False)" to do the (First Name) and then changing the 1 to a 2 for (Last Name).

It is returning an error and I cant find a website that helps.

Has anyone got an idea.

Thanks,

Comment: always try to use [index/match](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/) as it is [far better](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vlookup()` is going to be tricky, since you can only search right. You can use `Index/Match` instead:

In your sheet2, A2 (where your "First Name" cells start), you can do:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$9,MATCH($C2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9,0))`

Where:

`Sheet1!B$2:B$9` is the range of your First Names that you want to use to populate the other sheet.
`Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9` is the range of all the Account IDs.
`$C2` is the Account ID on Sheet2.

Then, you can drag that right to `B2`, and it should grab the Last Names.

Comment: @Zat - As mentioned above in the comment, `Index/Match` is a great tool to have. I highly suggest reading into it more. You can even use multiple variables to match.